# Scaling out Azure App Service

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-web-app-service

I have my web app hosted on Azure App services which i would like to scale out now.

**I have OWIN cookie Authentication for this to work on scaled out infrastructure.. What all do i need to consider?**

Comment: Oh too broad dude..

Answer (score 1):

> I have OWIN cookie Authentication for this to work on scaled out infrastructure.. What all do i need to consider?

If we want to scale out our web app, we need to make sure that our web application is stateless which means we can't store any data which dedicated to server instance. OWIN cookie Authentication is stateless and you don't need to modify your code before scaling out your web app.

Comment: Any update? If my reply help you solved  your issue, please mark it as answer. If you have further questions which related to this topic, please feel free to let me know.